Issue setting AWS ECS environment variables in runtime.exs with Elixir
I’m working on a project in Elixir that runs in a container deployed on AWS ECS. I’m trying to use environment variables to define the execution environment (ENVIRONMENT) and access them within my application.
Configuration
In my runtime.exs file, I am configuring like this:
if config_env() in [:prod, :stage] do
  environment = System.get_env("ENVIRONMENT") || "Devs"

  config :lxp, :aws_config,
    environment: environment
end

Then, I have the following module in my code:
defmodule Lxp.AwsConfig do
  def get_environment do
    Application.get_env(:lxp, :aws_config)[:environment] || "Devs"
  end
end

I understand that the get_environment function always returns “Devs”, which indicates that the ENVIRONMENT environment variable is not being read correctly from the container.

It sounds like you may not have an environment variable named ENVIRONMENT defined in the ECS task definition. Can you show your ECS Task definition? Or at least the environment section of the task definition?

This is my .tfvars file
vars_by_workspace = {
  qa = {
     ecs_web_app_config = {}
     map_container_environment = {
        POOL_SIZE = "10"
        SENDGRID_API_KEY = ""
        ENVIRONMENT = "Stage"
        ...
       }

    secrets = [...]
    }
  }
  prod = {
     ecs_web_app_config = {]
     map_container_environment = {
        POOL_SIZE = "10"
        SENDGRID_API_KEY = ""
        ENVIRONMENT = "Prod"
        ...
       }

    secrets = [...]
    }
  }

